# Populate second and third select box after change the selected value of the first box

Tags: php, jquery

Have three select boxes, at first the "device_sel" and "prob_sel" are disabled. When i choose value from the first select box, "customer_sel" i use $.post to populate device_sel. My problem is i what to do the same thing when i select value in "device_sel" then "prob_sel" populates. I think there is some error that i dont see in the $.post process when i try to populate prob_sel. When i change(or select for first time) value in device_sel, prob_sel keeps begin disabled and nothing happens.

Can someone spot error or typeo, been trying for hour to figure this out and cant find anything.

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#device_sel').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#prob_sel').attr('disabled', true);


        $('#customer_sel').change(function()
        {
            var cid = $('#customer_sel').attr("value");
            $.post("get_customers_devices.php", {cid:cid}, function(data)
            {
                $('#device_sel').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#device_sel').html(data);
            });
        });

        $('#device_sel').change(function()
        {
            var did = $('#device_sel').attr("value");
            jQuery.post("get_device_problems.php", {did:did}, function(data)
            {
                $('#prob_sel').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#prob_sel').html(data);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

get_customers_devices.php:

```
    <?php

include "FillSelect.class.php";

echo $fill->FillDeviceSelect($getdata->GetCustomersDevice($_POST['cid']));

?>
```

get_device_problems.php:

```
 <?php

include "FillSelect.class.php";

echo   $fill- >FillProblemSelect($getdata->GetDeviceProblems($_POST['did'])) ;

?>
```

GetCustomerDevice and GetDeviceProblems:

```
function GetCustomersDevice($cid)
    {
        try
         {
            $db = new PDO('sqlite:base.db') ;
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

            $pquery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE cid=:cid");
            $data = array("cid"=>$cid);
            $pquery -> execute($data) ;

            $rows = $pquery->fetchAll();

            return $rows;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();            
        }

        $db = NULL;
    }

    function GetDeviceProblems($did)
    {
        try
         {

            $db = new PDO('sqlite:base.db') ;
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

            $pquery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Problems p, Devices d WHERE d.did=:did");
            $data = array("did"=>$did);
            $pquery -> execute($data) ;

            $rows = $pquery->fetchAll();

            return $rows;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();            
        }

        $db = NULL;
    }
```

Finally FillDeviceSelect and FillProblemSelect:

```
function FillDeviceSelect($data)
    {
        $device = '<option value="0">Select option</option>';
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $device.= '<option value="'. $row['did'] .'">'. $row['device_name'] .'</option>';
        }

        return $device;
    }

function FillProblemSelect($data)
    {
        $problem = '<option value="0">Select option</option>';
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $problem .= '<option value="' . $row['pid']  .'">' .  $row['problem'] .'</option>';
        }

        return $problem;
    }
```

Solved it. Very very silli mistakes, get_device_problems not in same folder as my page but i did know that the file was saved in another folder and thats why my post call didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but I'd imagine that's because you have an onChange effect on `device_sel`, and you're then changing it's default value when you populate it with your onChange call from `customer_sel`.  Try unbinding your second change from `$('#device_sel').change(function()` and see if you have the same problem. (I apologize if I totally misunderstood the problem you're having)